# Azure Webjob function with no input parameters?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

Can I write a WebJob with a function that does not take any parameter? (it would be triggered either manually or by the scheduler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, simply create a console app with your function and deploy it as a triggered WebJob.

> Note: you don't have to use WebJobs SDK to create a WebJob.

Comment: Oh yes... i realized it watching: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2014/DEV-B342 (just after you wrote your answer... thanks!)